# Adding f(x) = x sin(x) to title of a plot

Tags: r, plot

How can I add f(x)=x sin(x) to the title of my plot. I tried:

```
curve(x*sin(x),0,2*pi,
      col='red',lwd=2,
      xlab=expression(paste(0<x)<2*pi),
      main=expression(f(x)=x sin(x)))
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By something like the following. You need to use proper syntax in the expression. See `?plotmath`.

```
curve(x*sin(x), 0, 2*pi,
      col = 'red', lwd = 2,
      xlab = expression(paste(0<x)<2*pi),
      main = expression(f(x)==x*sin(x)))
```

[image: Output]

Comment: `?expression` isn’t helpful here. You need `?plotmath`

Comment: @KonradRudolph Indeed, I remembered incorrectly. It's now corrected.

Comment: That worked. Thanks. Also, does anyone know of tutorials in using plot math? Any links?

Comment: @David As can be seen in `?plotmath`, `demo(plotmath)` is a good start.